# Get timestamps of current week

Tags: php, oop, datetime

I have a DateTime of current day. I need to get two unix timestamps of beggining and ending of current week. How can I use dateperiod or dateinterval class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$now = time();
$beginning_of_week = strtotime('last Monday', $now); // Gives you the time at the BEGINNING of the week
$end_of_week = strtotime('next Sunday', $now) + 86400; // Gives you the time at the END of the last day of the week
```

Comment: but whats to do when today is Monday? I got the week of 14 days.

Comment: Then check if today is Monday, and if it is replace 'last Monday' with 'today'. To see if it's currently Monday, do `if (date('w', $now()) == 1)`

Comment: Seems, also " UTC" should be appended to get UTC0 timeStamp

Comment: Please be aware that not all days have 86400 seconds, due to daylight saving time and random political changes.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (date('w', time()) == 1)
    $beginning_of_week = strtotime('Today',time()); 
else 
    $beginning_of_week = strtotime('last Monday',time()); 

if (date('w', time()) == 7)
    $end_of_week = strtotime('Today', time()) + 86400;
else 
    $end_of_week = strtotime('next Sunday', time()) + 86400;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static function getDaysInWeek($timestamp)
{       
    $monday = idate('w', $timestamp) == 1 ? $timestamp : strtotime("last Monday", $timestamp);

    $days = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i)
    {
        $days[$i] = strtotime('+' . $i . ' days', $monday);
    }
    return $days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is this (I'm assuming the usual European week format, replace with other day names to your liking):

```
$when = new DateTimeImmutable('1974-08-21 22:30:00'); // Wednesday
echo $when->modify('monday this week')->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
echo $when->modify('monday next week -1 second')->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
```

```
Mon, 19 Aug 1974 00:00:00 +0200
Sun, 25 Aug 1974 23:59:59 +0200
```

I've used `DateTimeImmutable` for simplicity, you can also use regular `DateTime` and `clone` objects.

Edge cases (date is either Monday or Sunday) should work as expected:

```
echo $when->modify('wednesday this week')->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
echo $when->modify('wednesday this week +1 day -1 second')->format('r'), PHP_EOL;
```

```
Wed, 21 Aug 1974 00:00:00 +0200
Wed, 21 Aug 1974 23:59:59 +0200
```